# Using a list of conditions to filter a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I wish to have a function which takes a list of conditions, of any length, and places an ampersand between all the conditions. Example code below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Sample', 'DP','GQ', 'AB'],
         data=[
               ['HG_12_34', 200, 35, 0.4],
               ['HG_12_34_2', 50, 45, 0.9],
               ['KD_89_9', 76, 67, 0.7],
               ['KD_98_9_2', 4, 78, 0.02],
               ['LG_3_45', 90, 3, 0.8],
               ['LG_3_45_2', 15, 12, 0.9]
               ])


def some_func(df, cond_list):

    # wrap ampersand between multiple conditions
    all_conds = ?

    return df[all_conds]

cond1 = df['DP'] > 40
cond2 = df['GQ'] > 40
cond3 = df['AB'] < 0.4


some_func(df, [cond1, cond2]) # should return df[cond1 & cond2]
some_func(df, [cond1, cond3, cond2]) # should return df[cond1 & cond3 & cond2]
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `functools.reduce` for that:

```
from functools import reduce

def some_func(df, cond_list):
    return df[reduce(lambda x,y: x&y, cond_list)]
```

Or, like [@AryaMcCarthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160733/using-a-list-of-conditions-to-filter-a-dataframe-in-pandas/43160759#comment73396595_43160759) says, you can use `and_` from the operator package:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_

def some_func(df, cond_list):
    return df[reduce(and_, cond_list)]
```

or with numpy - like [@ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160733/using-a-list-of-conditions-to-filter-a-dataframe-in-pandas/43160759#comment73396669_43160759) says - which has also a logical and reduction:

```
from numpy import logical_and

def some_func(df, cond_list):
    return df[logical_and.reduce(cond_list)]
```

All three versions produce - for your *sample input* - the following output:

```
>>> some_func(df, [cond1, cond2])
       Sample  DP  GQ   AB
1  HG_12_34_2  50  45  0.9
2     KD_89_9  76  67  0.7
>>> some_func(df, [cond1, cond2, cond3])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Sample, DP, GQ, AB]
Index: []
```

Comment: Might be even better to use `operator.and_` instead of your custom lambda.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy: yeah that is indeed more neat.

Comment: Or, from numpy: `np.logical_and.reduce([cond1, cond2, cond3])`